# Is it possible to create nested lists in the WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, wysiwyg, posting

I'm looking to set up WP for a user that does not know or care about HTML, so I need everything to work in the WYSIWYG editor.

She'll be working on posts that have lots of nested bullet lists, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Any thoughts?

Tabbing didn't work, clicking the buttons didn't work. Hitting 'indent' could be hacked into a solution, but it's certainly not ideal and I don't know how consistent it'll be. I know I can fiddle with the HTML, but like I said, I don't want to get into that. I can copy/paste from Word, but that's a terrible solution.

I'm open to a plugin or alternate editor, though that's not ideal either.

Comment: Hmm, odd. I just tried hitting 'indent' again and it worked! Last time I tried, it added a `blockquote` to the li instead of adding a nested list. I guess I'll probably just answer my own question or delete it...

Comment: Yep... indenting a part of the list would create one step deeper list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In extended toolbar view (Alt+Shift+Z), Pressing the "indent" button to a list or part of list would be make it one step more deeper